# Amending IF statement in VBA to ensure that named range is populated with correct formulae

Tags: vba, excel

I appear to have an issue with my code. It will populate the whole of the named range `"Table_LM"` with '0's, when in reality I just want to populate those whose value in what I've named as `"Table_Month"` with a '0' when the value in `"Table_Month"` is greater than/equal to 10. I assume its just me wrongly defining the IF statement...

Also, I feel like I can make what I am trying to achieve much more efficient and quick. Does anyone have any suggestions? I can add further info if needs be...

Below is syntax:

```
    Sub Oval2_Click()
    Dim c As Range
    Const upperlimit As Integer = 10
    For Each c In Range("Table_Month")
      With Range("Table_LM")
        If c.Value >= upperlimit Then
            .Value = 0
        Else
            .Formula = "=table_month*table_long"
            .Value = .Value
        End If
      End With
     Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: When you use `With Range("Table_LM")` and then use `.Value = 0` below, that's the same as `Range("Table_LM").Value = 0`. How does Table_LM play into this? Do you even need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because `Table_LM` "doesn't know" that you are looping over the cells of `Table_Month`. You can do something like this:

```
Sub Oval2_Click()
Dim c As Range
Dim i as Long
Dim NRows as Long
Dim j as Long
Dim NCols as Long
Const upperlimit As Integer = 10
For i = 1 to NRows
  For j = 1 to NCols
    If Range("Table_Month").Cells(i,j).Value >= upperlimit Then
        Range("Table_LM").Cells(i,j).Value = 0
    Else
        Range("Table_LM").Cells(i,j).Formula = "=table_month*table_long"
        ' Range("Table_LM").Cells(i,j).Value = .Value
    End If
  Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Couple more comments:

- You'll need to set the values of `NRows` and `NCols` before entering the loops.
- I wasn't clear on what you wanted to do with `.Formula = "=table_month*table_long"`. If you intended to pair-wise multiply each cell in table_month a corresponding cell in table_long you'll need to modify the code to get the cell addresses.
- I wasn't clear on what you wanted to do with `.Value = .Value`. In the previous line of code you set the formula, so the value will get calculated.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
For Each c In Range("Table_Month")
    If c.Value >= upperlimit Then
        .Value = 0
    Else
        .Formula = "=table_month*table_long"
        .Value = .Value
    End If
Next c
```